# Is it correct/idiomatic to omit "once" in some cases?

Tags: expressions, writing-style

Example:

> **Once again**, I traveled three hours just to sit alone.
>
> **Again**, I traveled three hours just to sit alone.
>
> ---
>
> We decided to go to the balcony. **Once there**, we leaned on the railing,
>   side by side.
>
> We decided to go to the balcony. **There**, we leaned on the railing, side
>   by side.

Do they differ a lot? Is this something a native English speaker would do in informal speech?

Comment: It sounds odd and non-native to my ear and eye to omit the "once".

Comment: It sounds fine. You can basically leave out any non-essential word in a sentance (in informal circumstances).

Comment: Non-essential by who's decision, @bjb568?  That's a very broad statement that as a native speaker, I do not believe to be true.

Comment: Some words can be left out, because there are syntactic rules for deleting them in certain circumstances. And in fact some of them are likely not essential, because they're predictable; but deleting them often reduces clarity because it increases ambiguity. The more little guide words you leave out the more possible interpretations you invite; information is information, and deletion is deletion. Certainly, however, a complex intensifier like _just_ is neither required nor forbidden by any gross syntactic phenomenon.

Comment: @Kristina You tell I'm saying without missing words, like this. (can, what, the, with, sentance)

Comment: @bjb568, yes, kinda  - but it's not really good English, is it?  I certainly wouldn't make that recommendation to anyone.  I think John Lawler said it very well, actually.

Comment: @bjb568  Y cn lv t ll th vwls nd stll b ndrstd

Comment: @Barmar Ar sabstotet tham far athor vewals!

Answer (score 1):

The first case, "once again", connotes a feeling of willingness to repeat the action with the hope of it being a final iteration.

The second case, "again", lacks the connotation, leaving reiteration more open ( no specification of speaker's feeling about it ).

Examples:

"Once again, I let the dog out. I hoped it would be the last time today." ( first case )

"Again, I let the dog out. He probably still didn't need to pee -- but I wasn't going to make my Persian rug pay for it if I was wrong." ( second case )